# Which loop can best fit in doing the following?

Tags: php

I am trying to do a stuff like playing ads based on interest of user. there are certain other parameters set by advertiser. If all those parameters match with a certain user profile then that ad has to be played to him,else check with the next ad..If the list of ad ends and none of them matched then remove one of the parameter and then match. finally if none of the parameters matched then play the ad which is at the top of the list. I have two seperate tables for user and ad, will it be good to join them and fetch data match?
Can anyone tell me which loop will best fit here?

This is what i have tried till now.

`public function adpreferences($ads,$userid){

```
    for($i=0;$i<count($ads);$i++){
    $sql="SELECT ua.ads,ua.frm_age,ua.t_age,ua.user_income,ua.user_occupation,ua.user_gender,U.gender,U.income,U.occupation, U.dob FROM  user_ad ua LEFT JOIN users U  ON U.userid =ua.userid where U.userid='$userid' AND ua.ads='$ads[$i]'";
    $res=@mysql_query($sql);
    $numOFRows  =@mysql_num_rows($res);

    if($numOFRows > 0){
        while ($result = @mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $returnArr[]=$result;
            $user_occ=$result['user_occupation'];
            $user_incm=$result['user_income'];
            $gen=$result['user_gender'];
            $f_age=$result['frm_age'];
            $t_age=$result['t_age'];
            //print_r ($returnArr);
            $dob= $result['dob'];
            $birthdate = new DateTime($dob);
            $today   = new DateTime('today');
            $age = $birthdate->diff($today)->y;
            //print_r ($age);

        //return (array($result));
         for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
            for($j=0;$j<count($ads);$j++){
            if ($ads[$j]!==0){

            if(($user_occ==$result['occupation'])&&($user_incm==$result['income'])&&($gen==$result['gender'] || $gen =='Both')&&(($age>= $f_age) && ($age<= $t_age))){

                $ads[]=$result['ads'];
                }
                return $ads[$j];
            }

            }

             for($k=0;$k<count($ads);$k++){
                 if ($ads[$k]!==0){
             if(($user_occ==$result['occupation'])&&($gen==$result['gender'])&&(($age>= $f_age) && ($age<= $t_age))){

                 $ads[]=$result['ads'];
                 return $ads[$k];
                 }
             }
             }
             for($m=0;$m<count($ads);$m++){
                 if ($ads[$m]!==0){
             if(($gen==$result['gender'])&&(($age>= $f_age) && ($age<= $t_age))){

                 $ads[]=$result['ads'];
                 return $ads[$m];
                 }
             }
             }
             for($n=0;$n<count($ads);$n++){
                 if ($ads[$n]!==0){
             if(($gen==$result['gender'])||($gen=='Both'))
            { 
                 $ads[]=$result['ads'];

                 return $ads[$n];
                 }


                }

            }

        }
        return $ads[0];

    }

 }
 }
 }``
```

As suggested i used foreach loop and tried this.

```
while ($result = @mysql_fetch_array($res)){

            $dob= $result['dob'];
            $birthdate = new DateTime($dob);
            $today   = new DateTime('today');
            $age = $birthdate->diff($today)->y;
            //print_r ($age);



        foreach($result as $array){

            for($i=0;$i<count($ads);$i++){
            if(($array['user_occupation']==$array['occupation'])&& ($array['user_income']==$array['income']) && ($array['user_gender']==$array['fbgender'] || $array['user_gender']=='Both') && (($age>=$array['frm_age'])&&($age<=$array['t_age']))){

                return $ads[$i];
                break;
            }
            elseif(($array['user_occupation']==$array['occupation']) && ($array['user_gender']==$array['fbgender'] || $array['user_gender']=='Both') && (($age>=$array['frm_age'])&&($age<=$result['t_age']))){
                //return $ads[$i];
                break;
            }
            elseif(($array['user_gender']==$array['fbgender'] || $array['user_gender']=='Both') && (($age>=$array['frm_age'])&&($age<=$array['t_age']))){
                //return $ads[$i];
                break;
            }
            elseif(($array['user_gender']==$array['fbgender'] || $array['user_gender']=='Both')){
                //return $ads[$i];
                break;
            }
            else{
                //return $ads[0];
            }
        }

        }
```

But i am getting error like undefined variable $array and illegal offset 'user_occupation',illegal offset 'occupation' and so on...

Comment: Can you show what have you tried till now ?

Comment: *We Deal With Codes Not With Theory.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `foreach()` loop with a switch on the arguments, keep track of which ad and how many requirements were fullfilled, once the loop finished, get the best match and show it to the user

Answer (score 0):

You could foreach through the ads and check a condition.

However, if there's a large number of ads you could consider storing them as an array (if not already) to foreach through, or even storing them in a DB (like mysql) and select ONLY the specifc ad needed (would be not doubt faster than foreach if there are a lot of ads to loop through). If mysql returns multiple results, you can fetch the results and loop through with a while loop.